# Cannot get value from db when "select Contact From table where Name = 'name'"

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I am trying to build a simple house loan application using Tkinter n Mysql in python. My function is basically want the user to key in the name and contact number and get the contact number form database to match with user key in contact.But the problem i face is when the name i insert is correct, i cannot get the contact from the db. Any problem to my command

```
sql = "SELECT 'Contact' FROM `table` WHERE Name = 'name'"
```

Below are the entire code

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkMessageBox import *
from sys import exit
import MySQLdb
import os





class application(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master= master
        self.L1 = Label(self,text="Application Loan")
        self.L1.pack(side=TOP)
        self.L2 = Label(self, image=logo).pack(side=LEFT)
        self.B1 = Button(self, text="car loan",command = self.car_loan)
        self.B1.pack(side = LEFT)
        self.L3 = Label(self,image=logo1).pack(side=RIGHT)
        self.B2 = Button(self, text="house loan", command = self.house_loan)
        self.B2.pack(side=BOTTOM)

def house_loan(self):
    self.house = Tk()
    self.house.title("house loan")
    self.house.L12 = Label(self.house, text="Thank you for choosing us. Please left your contact number, our staff will contact you for more detail")
    self.house.L12.pack(side=TOP)
    self.house.L6= Label(self.house, text="Name").pack()
    self.house.E8 = Entry(self.house,textvariable=.var1)
    self.house.E8.pack()
    self.house.L7= Label(self.house, text="Contact").pack()
    self.house.E9 = Entry(self.house,textvariable=var4)
    self.house.E9.pack()
    self.house.B4=Button(self.house,text="submit",command=self.Thankyou)
    self.house.B4.pack()

def Thankyou(self):
    name = self.house.E8.get()
    print name
    #global Contact
    global Contact
    Contact = NONE
    self.db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","bank" )
    cursor =self.db.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT 'Contact' FROM `table` WHERE Name = 'name'"
    print Contact
    cursor.execute(sql)
    input=self.house.E9.get()
    print input
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in results:

        Name = row[0]
        Age = int(row[1])
        Monthly_income = int(row[2])
        Contact = row[3]
        Email = row[4]

    if(input != Contact):
        sql = "UPDATE table SET Contact = 'input' \
        WHERE NAME = 'var1'"
        showinfo("Your contact number was updated","Our staff will contact you as soon as possible")

    else:
        showinfo("Thank you","Our staff will contact you as soon as possible")

    cursor.close()
    self.db.commit()

if __name__ == "__main__" :
table='table'
root = Tk()
root.title("Loan Application")

global logo
global logo1
var1 = StringVar()
var2 = IntVar()
var3= IntVar()
var4 = IntVar()
logo = PhotoImage(file = 'car.gif').subsample(3,3)
logo1 = PhotoImage(file = 'house1.gif').subsample(3,3)
application(root).pack(expand=TRUE)
root.mainloop()
```

print Contact give none (when i enter the correct name that exist in db)
I try to cancel contact = none but it will give me error show

```
NameError: global name 'Contact' is not defined
```

I have no idea what goes wrong. Anyone can help?

Comment: Is this code within a class? Where is `var1` defined? Can you post the entire code?

Comment: You also don't assign contact to anything after setting it to none, so not sure what you expected there

Comment: Since your code is not a [self-contained](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, I'll go on a limb and guess the problem is with this line `self.house.E8 = Entry(self.house,textvariable=.var1).pack()`. What you store in `E8` is the result of the `pack()` method, which returns none. While you should treat it similar to the `L12` variable, where you store the `Entry()` object and just pack it later on.

Comment: @cricket_007 this is my entire code

Comment: @Reti43 i try to pack like L12 variable but cannot work too

Comment: You're supposed to fetch the value from the `Entry` object. Therefore, you need to do `name = self.house.E8.get()`.

Comment: @Reti43 it work thank you!! but another question is why i cannot get the contact from the data base? Is it my select command wrong?

Comment: No idea, since I haven't installed the MySQLdb module. However, if you have a question regarding that, you should create a new question, since this one has to do with how to get the text from a text entry.